# Use Android Studio With Maven ONLY

Tags: maven, gradle, android-studio

All I want to do is use Android Studio without converting to Gradle. I **MUST** use maven (Client Requirements). **How can I accomplish this?**

I was able to get this working by opening up the pom.xml file but every time I close the project and reopen it, gradle is forced on me and I can't run anymore. Project layout also changes on me.

When I open up the project the first time using pom.xml, the module looks like this:
[image]

When I close the project and open up a 2nd time, the module looks like this:
(With the inability to run because Run/Debug says 'No Android facet found in the module')
[image]

I can get back to my original state by doing File->Open and reselecting the pom.xml file. I make sure to hit no on the first pop-up:

[image]

I blanked out my build.gradle file like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}
repositories {
}
dependencies {
}
```

Extra Notes:

1. Exported from eclipse ADT for a build.gradle file. Android Studio was missing all External Libraries that were Maven
   Dependencies.
2. Started my own build.gradle file to indlude dependencies but I don't want to maintain two separate files (build.gradle & pom.xml).
3. Deleted the build.gradle file and anything gradle related in the android project folder before reopening but that did nothing.
4. Developing on Linux OS Android Studio version 0.4.2

Comment: If you want to use Maven as your build system, you'll probably have less frustration using IntelliJ instead of Android Studio. IntelliJ 13 ships with the same Android plugin as Studio and has much of the same functionality.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks Scott. Android Studio offers better assistance than eclipse when developing layouts for different screen sizes. Hopefully IntelliJ includes that.

Comment: I noticed this comment recently: "Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: App, **Mobile. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project."

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to answer my own questions but I thought a work around might help others in this case.

What I noticed is that Android Studio fights between gradle and maven and chooses gradle if you have a gradlefile for the project as well as maven.

**Work Around**

1. Open Module Settings
2. Remove all modules. Select the module and hit the minus key to
   delete.
3. Click yes on the prompt.
4. Open up Maven Projects and click the plus key
5. Browse to your pom file and hit open.